# execution counting jump in control flow

Tags: gcov

I get the following annotation of my code. I understand that the line 1076 was executed 209 times and the line 1078 was executed 2 times. From here I can conclude that the line 1082 should be executed 209 - 2 = 207 times. But it is not the case. Why?

```
209: 1076:  if (some condition) { 
  -: 1077:        // some condition happen 
  2: 1078:        LOG("some condition happen”); 
  -: 1079:        return STATUS_DONE; 
  -: 1080:  } 
  -: 1081: 
408: 1082:  if (another condition) {
```

Thanks in advance, Stella